# Transfer event for zero amount

Tags: contract-development, transactions, ether, contract-design, tokens

Should I emit `Transfer` event, when zero amount of Ether or of a token is transferred?

Variants of the answer:

- yes
- no
- both are OK

Answer (score 1):

There's no harm in emitting the event for both.

Events are more about letting an external entity that something (ex. a function call) happened with certain parameters. If there are zero cases, let the external entity handle that scenario instead of choosing for them.

Comment: From the [EIP-20 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#transfer) *Transfers of 0 values MUST be treated as normal transfers and fire the Transfer event.*